# print the first character after the same element in every line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to print the first character after an element that occurs in each line.

w.txt:

> USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
>
> osboxes  tty7     :0               22:23   42:15   2.27s  0.23s
> cinnamon-session --session cinnamon
>
> osboxes  pts/1    192.168.1.17   22:25    1:26   0.06s  0.00s nano
> urandom.py
>
> osboxes  pts/3   192.168.1.17   22:25    1:26   0.06s  0.00s nano
> urandom.py
>
> osboxes  pts/0    192.168.56.117   22:25    1:26   0.06s  0.00s nano
> urandom.py

f = open("w.txt", "r")
w = f.read()

```
tty = (w.split('/')[1])print(tty[0])
```

The above returns the id of the first pts

> 1

but I want it to do this for every line, and return all the integers seperated by a comma
eg:

> 1,3,0

Ive tried the following but just returns every character in the line after 1 a bunch of times.

```
tty = w
for line in w:
  print(tty.split('/')[1])
```

thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to scan for any digit after a `/`. This will give you strings, but you can convert those to integers fairly easily.

```
import re

with open(path, 'r') as file:
    found = re.findall(r'/(\d)', file.read())
    # ['1', '3', '0']

[int(i) for i in found]
# [1, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list commprehension to check '/' in each character of each line then print unpacked int splitted index 0 from list with comma separator

```
with open("w.txt") as f:
    print(*[int(line.split('/')[1][0]) for line in f.readlines() if '/' in line], sep=',')

# 1,3,0
```